# Spring @Transactional annotation behaves weird

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

I have the following method:

```
@Transactional
public void onEmailMessage() {

    this.departmentService.removeUserFromDepartments(user, depsids);
    this.departmentService.getDepartmentUsers(user.id); 
}
```

The weird thing when i invoke this method, the first line:

```
  this.departmentService.removeUserFromDepartments(user, depsids);
```

is called but the DB is not changing at all and the user is still connected to the deparment (many to many relation)

afterwards the method :

```
   this.departmentService.getDepartmentUsers(user.id);
```

is called and returns users that are connected to the department including the removed user from line#1.

when the method returns - if i check the DB the user i removed is actually been removed from the table!

can i make the query return the actual updated values??

Comment: enable sql logging and you'll get an idea as to when the sql instructions are actually executed.

Comment: Interesting. The JPA implementation (I'm assuming that you are using one) should know that the element was removed, inside the same transaction. Maybe it hasn't been connected to the transaction manager, or maybe you set a 2nd level cache that is not transactional. I'm just guessing since I haven't worked with a JPA in a while, but the solution should not be to force a flush or to split it in two transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing weird about this. You are performing two different queries within the same transaction. Persistence context is updated, but the transaction hasn't been committed yet, and you can't see your changes after first line is finished. Transaction is a set of statements (in this case - statements created by those two methods of yours) which gets executed after `commit` is invoked. When the whole (onEmailMessage) method finished it's job, the transaction is committed and you are seeing the changes.

**The solutions would be:**

Make them as two separate transactions. For e.g:

```
@Transactional
public void removeUser(...) {
    someInstance.departmentService.removeUserFromDepartments(user, depsids);
}
```

And:

```
@Transactional
public List<?> getUsers(...) {
    return someInstance.departmentService.getDepartmentUsers(user.id);
}
```

Then the highest level would be `onEmailMessage()` method, which has to be non-transactional and in separate class then these two methods above. Call them both in this level and it will work.

Comment: When removing the transactional annotation from my wrapper method it actually works. both other methods are transactional as well

Comment: If they are transactional then yes - it will work. It just the matter of levels - how are you managing them. All your methods for e.g. in controllers should be non-transactional, it is the highest level of your application. The DB level, all your methods which are calling entity manager's methods like: persit, merge, etc, should be non-transactional as well, because this is the lowest level. All your transactions should be handled in the middle level classes, it then makes them easier to be managed at the highest level. It is not necessary, but recommended.

Comment: `When removing the transactional annotation from my wrapper method it actually works.` If you are keeping your @Transactional on the onEmailMessage() method and other methods which are called in it are transactional, new transaction for them won't be created, only one transaction from the higher level will be performed. There can be some cases where you need other transaction opened in the existing one, so for that purpose you'll need to use: `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. But in this case there is no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked it as `Transactional`. Changes in `DB` is made after executing all the queries. Either all of the operations will be committed or none.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction hasn't been committed yet so changes won't necessarily have been written to the DB.

You could try calling

```
entityManager.flush();
```

after `removeUserFromDepartments()` but before `getDepartmentUsers()` to force the DB changes to be written before the commit.